# First and last active class in flexslider now work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

I am using FlexSlider jquery plugin in a carrousel that show different testimonials in a web page, I have a problem with active class for last item in the first loop and first item after first loop, the active class is not asigned and the special effect not work well. If I made click on each item the class is assigned but first item is not moved to initial position.

My html code look like this:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class="client">
                <div class="t-box">
                    <blockquote>
                        Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. 
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="client">
                <div class="t-box">
                    <blockquote>
                        Praesent egestas neque eu enim. Vestibulum suscipit nulla quis orci. Maecenas tempus,
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; max-width: 980px; overflow: hidden; margin: auto; ">
    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <div class="name">
                    <h3>Vestibulum volutpat pretium</h3>
                    <small>Cras risus ipsum</small>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="name">
                    <h3>Sed in libero</h3>
                    <small>Donec vitae orci <br />Praesent ac.</small>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="name">
                    <h3>Praesent vestibulum dapibus</h3>
                    <small>Duis lobortis massa <br/>Sed mollis eros.</small>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="name">
                    <h3>Sed aliquam ultrices</h3>
                    <small>Donec elit libero<br/>In hac habitasse</small>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am initialize flexslider with this code:

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    itemWidth: 280,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider',
    slideshowSpeed: 5000, 
    maxItems: 1,
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    sync: "#carousel",
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    maxItems: 1,
});
```

The full example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7s8ruas8/)

What's wrong in my implementation of flexslider?

Comment: your problem is not clear..can you please post your entire code..

Comment: and also..you are applying the second flexslider on element with id "slides". But in you html there is no such element.

Comment: @nikhil the full code is in a link at the end of post in a fiddle, If you can see in my script I am initializing second slider with $('#slider')  this id is the first div in my code, both slider work, but active class behaviour is not correctly at the end of slider and in the start of the second loop.